# Passing to another page using form and window.open. The other page is not receiving the value

Tags: javascript, php

This is my initial page code

> $_POST["i"] is the url that I have sent from the previous page and it works fine here. This is also the value that I am trying to send to the next page through the hidden field.

```
<form name="f1" method="post" action="window.open(/mydir/product-cat/brookbond?add-to-cart=89" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="89" data-product_sku="" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple)">
<input type="hidden" name="k" value="<?php echo $_POST["i"]; ?>" >
<img src="<?php echo $_POST["i"]; ?>" />
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Receiving end code in the next page

```
<?php echo $_POST["k"]; ?>
```

It is not receiving any value and thus not printing anything.
Everything else works as expected.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I  cannot substitute the window.open function, it serves a definite purpose.

Comment: Have you checked the hidden field .... means is $_POST['i'] contain any value or blank

Comment: I went to the page source and saw that it's working fine. It has the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant of solutions, but maybe you can add it to the url of the `window.open`.

```
... window.open(/mydir/product-cat/brookbond?add-to-cart=89 
       & k="<?php echo rawurlencode($_POST["i"]);?>"
```

Comment: How do I catch it in the other page? Same way?

Comment: Same way as you catch `add-to-cart`: `$_GET['k'];`

Comment: Thanks a lot Michel :-) Will try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can't send it the way you do. If you don't want to reload page and send post data then you need to use AJAX.

On [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you will find examples how to do it. You need to bind submit() event for form and then send ajax request to the page you want and process the results.

The other option is to use **GET** instead of **POST** but this window.open doesn't look good anyway.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Will try it out and comment back! :-)

Comment: and I tried using GET. yes, you are right....it screws up the link because of window.open